# Joining lines with awk and sed

Tags: sed, awk

I like to join lines following {st,corridor,tunnel} into one line using AWK or SED

```
Input 

abcd 
efgjk
st 
wer
dfgh
corridor 
weerr
tunnel 
twdf

Desired output


abcd  
efgjk st  
wer 
dfgh corridor  
weerr tunnel 
twdf
```

Comment: May I ask whether the use of awk or sed is truly a requirement for your situation?  Are you trying to learn awk and sed techniques?  Or do you just want to [solve the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 2):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk '!/st|corridor|tunnel/ { if (line) print line; line = $0; next } { line = line " " $0 } END { print line }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
abcd 
efgjk st 
wer
dfgh corridor 
weerr tunnel 
twdf
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;s/\n\(st\|corridor\|tunnel\)\s*$/ \1/;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, an awk version that reads the whole file into memory first (not recommended for large files):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {i=1} {line[i++] = $0} END {j=1; while (j<i) {if (match(line[j+1], /^(st|corridor|tunnel)$/)) {print line[j] " " line[j+1]; j+=2} else print line[j++];}}' streets
abcd
efgjk st
wer
dfgh corridor
weerr tunnel
twdf
```

I'll leave you with the exercise of doing this one-or-two-lines-at-a-time. :)

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`

```
BEGIN {
    s["st"]=s["corridor"]=s["tunnel"]
}

$1 in s {
    print prev, $1
}

!($1 in s) {
    if (prev) print prev
    prev = $1
}
```